# How to set up a custom effortless navigation in dired?

Tags: key-bindings, dired

I would like to configure dired so its navigation would behave as classic file managers do. I.e. binding

- `M-<left>` to go backward in navigation history, while staying within the current dired buffer
- `M-<right>` to go forward in navigation history, while staying within the current dired buffer
- `M-<up>` to go to parent directory, while staying within the current dired buffer
- `RET` to enter a directory, while staying within the current dired buffer

Is it possible? If yes, how could it be done?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145377/discussion-on-question-by-crocefisso-how-to-set-up-a-custom-effortless-navigatio); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

See below, for correction after understanding that by previous/next you meant navigation history and not movement to previous/next line.

---

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-<left>") #'dired-previous-line) ; Or `diredp-previous-line`, if you use Dired+

(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-<right>") #'dired-next-line) ; Or `diredp-next-line`, if you use Dired+

(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-<up>") #'dired-up-directory) ; Or `diredp-up-directory`, if you use Dired+
```

`RET` already does what you request.

There are standard key bindings for each of those actions: `p`, `n`, `^`, `RET`.  You might try learning them. Keys `p` (or `C-p`) and `n` (or `C-n`) are often bound in Emacs buffers to "previous" and "next commands appropriate to the major mode.

Library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) enhances the first three of those in minor ways:

- `p` and `n` optionally wrap around when at the beginning/end of the file listing
- On MS Windows, if you're already at the root directory, `^` visits a navigable list of Windows drives.

---

**UPDATE**, after you wrote your comment underlining that you mean browsing/navigation history and not previous/next line in the buffer:

For "browsing/navigation history" it depends on what you mean. That can mean almost anything in Emacs. Neither Dired+ nor vanilla Dired offer commands for navigation history. And that term is too vague in a question to mean anything.

But keep in mind that the default behavior of Dired (and Dired+) creates a new buffer for each directory or file you visit.

You say (see below) that that's what you *don't* want. But with that default behavior you can easily and quickly get to any directory or file that you've previously visited! Just use `C-x b` with `M-p` or `M-n` or `M-r` or `M-s`. Or use completion against the buffer name.

Other than that, here are usual, general Emacs ways to navigate through your browsing history. They're not at all specific to Dired.

- When you input a command with `M-x`, `M-p` gives you the previous command (repeat to go back in the history).
- You can often go back in your history of keys/commands using `C-x ESC ESC` (or `C-x M-ESC`, which is the same thing). It shows you the Lisp expression for the previous "complex" command, and (again) you can use `M-p` repeatedly to go back further in the history.
- Use `C-u C-SPC` to move backward among the places in the current buffer where you've set the mark (using `C-SPC` or any other command that sets the mark). Use `C-u C-x C-@` to move among the places in different buffers where you've set the mark (one mark per buffer). See `C-h k C-SPC`.

---

As for your comment that Dired commands that visit a file or directory create a new buffer: yes, of course they do. That's generally what Emacs users want.

But there's an easy way to not have `RET` do that: just use `a` instead. That's command `dired-find-alternate-file`, which just uses `find-alternate-file` (which is bound globally to `C-x C-v`).

With Dired+ you can get this behavior by default, and for all commands that visit directories -- e.g., `^` in addition to `n` and `p` and `RET`.  Just put this in your init file:

```lisp
(diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
```

And you can toggle this behavior any time, using `C-M-R` (aka `C-M-S-r`).

Comment: `RET` opens a new dired buffer.

Comment: Also `dired-up-directory` opens a new buffer. And I don't exactly get what `dired-previous-line` and `dired-next-line` do. But they don't seem to go backward and forward in browsing history.

Comment: I didn't try to evolve my question in the comment. I just explained why the provided solution didn't answer the question. Also, the "navigation history" part was already in my question before I started commenting it.

Comment: I added `dired+` in my solution. What I miss with `dired+` is the fortification provided by `denote-dired-mode`. Regarding what I meant by navigation history, it is something similar to web browsers behavior when you go backward and forward in browsing history (also bound with M-left and M-right). File managers such as Thunar also have this functionality (also bound with M-left and M-right).

Comment: Define browsing history. That's the problem. In my answer I noted a few different kinds of "browsing" (there are many more). A web browser has one kind: URL1, URL2, URL3,...URLN. Just URLs. Same thing with Emacs Info nodes - just node after node. But what if you also mix in searching, moving over various kinds of things, etc. You'll note that a web browser doesn't include navigating by searching on a web page (e.g. `C-f`) in its forward-and-back browsing history. In Emacs there are any number of different ways and places to move - there's no single, simple notion of browsing navigation.

Comment: Yes, what I meant by navigating history is not navigating through all the actions made within dried, but only through all the taken paths. As GUI-based file managers do, confer [Thunar](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start) or [Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Files) M-left and M-right.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the single buffer part of the question (bullet point 3 and 4). Two additional packages can provide with a solution: `dired-single` or `dired+`.

Firstly you have to bind `dired-up-directory` to `M-<up>`

```el
(use-package dired
  :ensure nil
  :config
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-<up>") #'dired-up-directory))
```

Then, if you prefer to use `dired-single`, add:

```el
(use-package dired-single
  :config
  (define-key dired-mode-map [remap dired-up-directory]'dired-single-up-directory)
  (define-key dired-mode-map [remap dired-find-file] 'dired-single-buffer))
```

If you prefer to use `dired+`, add:

```el
(use-package dired+
  :ensure nil
  :init (add-to-list 'load-path "PATH")
  :config (diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir 1))
```

Where "PATH" is the path where `dired+.el` is located.